# celerybeat raise exception "can't pickle module object" when putting both celery and celerybeat config in the same file?

Tags: python, exception, config, celery, celerybeat

I put celery/celerybeat config in the same settings.py:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from datetime import timedelta

CELERY_IMPORTS = ('some module',)

BROKER_URL = "****"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "****"

#other celery config
```

When I start celerybeat, it raise TypeError:('can't pickle module object')

If I remove the "CELERY_IMPORTS" line, the celerybeat can work well.

I doubt How "CELERY_IMPORTS" can affect the celerybeat while celerybeat doesn't need "CELERY_INPORTS"